# How can I suppress the line numbers output using R CMD BATCH?

Tags: r, stdout

If I have an R script:

```
print("hi")
commandArgs()
```

And I run it using:

```
r CMD BATCH --slave --no-timing test.r output.txt
```

The output will contain:

```
[1] "hi"
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/x86_64/R"
[2] "-f"                                                         
[3] "test.r"                                                     
[4] "--restore"                                                  
[5] "--save"                                                     
[6] "--no-readline"                                              
[7] "--slave"
```

How can i suppress the line numbers[1]..[7] in the output so only the output of the script appears?

Comment: @aL3xa If you would have written than up as an answer, I would have probably voted it up. But as a comment I overlooked it -- thinking "what does `cat` have to do with anything?" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, mbq is right -- use `Rscript`, or, if it floats your boat, [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html):

```
$ cat /tmp/tommy.r 
#!/usr/bin/r

cat("hello world\n")
print(argv[])
$ /tmp/tommy.r a b c
hello world
[1] "a" "b" "c"
$
```

You probably want to look at CRAN packages [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=getopt) and [optparse](http://cran.r-project.org/package=optparse) for argument-parsing as you'd do in other scripting languages/

Comment: This answer is misleading. I don't think the problem is with *how* the R script is invoked. The solution is to use `cat` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 14):

Use `cat` instead of `print` if you want to suppress the line numbers (`[1]`, `[2]`, ...) in the output.

I think you are also going to want to pass command line arguments. I think the easiest way to do that is to create a file with the RScript [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

For example, create a file called `args.r`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
cat(args, sep = "\n")
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x args.r` and then you can run it with `./args.r ARG1 ARG2`

FWIW, passing command line parameters with the `R CMD BATCH ...` syntax is a pain. Here is how you do it: `R CMD BATCH "--args ARG1 ARG2" args.r` Note the quotes. More discussion [here](http://projects.uabgrid.uab.edu/r-group/wiki/CommandLineProcessing)

UPDATE: changed shebang line above from `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` to `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` in response to @mbq's comment (thanks!)

Comment: This shebang is not too fortunate, since Rscript jumps across the filesystem in various distros (and 32-64 bit versions). Yet `env` is here to save the day, and `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` should always work.

Comment: @mbq although my original shebang was not fortunate, your comment was, so thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `commandArgs(TRUE)` and run your script with `Rscript`.

EDIT: Ok, I've misread your question. David has it right.

Comment: While using commandArgs(TRUE) is a nice trick when doing command parsing, it does not address the question, namely how to suppress the `[1]`, `[2]`, and so on.

Comment: @DavidJames True, the question was misleading, thus this answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Stop Rscript from command-numbering the output from print

By default, R makes `print(...)` pre-pend command numbering to stdout like this:

```
print("we get signal")
```

Produces:

> [1] "we get signal"

Rscript lets the user change the definition of functions like print, so it serves our purpose by default:

```
print = cat
print("we get signal")
```

Produces:

> we get signal

Notice the command numbering and double quoting is gone.

### Get more control of print by using R first class functions:

```
my_print <- function(x, ...){ 
    #extra shenanigans for when the wind blows from the east on tuesdays, go here. 
    cat(x) 
} 
print = my_print 
print("we get signal")
```

Prints:

> we get signal

If you're using print as a poor mans debugger... We're not laughing at you, we're laughing with you.